# How to replace a widget with another in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

In my GUI application, I'm displaying a camera stream to a user. Now the thing is that the user will be able to see stream from only one camera at a time and in order to see streams from other cameras he must enter the credentials of the new camera like `username`, `password` and `camera IP`.

**I want to do this using a dialog box**. I was able to do that but everytime a new window popped up. I do how to switch between different cameras using `QStackedLayout` but this time I can't use that because the camera objects are created at runtime.

All I want is that on press of a button a dialog box should appear and the camera must be replaced once the credentials are entered.

code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import cv2
import imutils

class CameraWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """Independent camera feed
    Uses threading to grab IP camera frames in the background

    @param width - Width of the video frame
    @param height - Height of the video frame
    @param stream_link - IP/RTSP/Webcam link
    @param aspect_ratio - Whether to maintain frame aspect ratio or force into fraame
    """

    def __init__(self, username, password, camera_ip, width=0, height=0, stream_link=0, aspect_ratio=False, parent=None, deque_size=1):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize deque used to store frames read from the stream
        self.deque = deque(maxlen=deque_size)

        # Slight offset is needed since PyQt layouts have a built in padding
        # So add offset to counter the padding 
        self.screen_width = 640
        self.screen_height = 480
        self.maintain_aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio

        self.camera_stream_link = 'rtsp://{}:{}@{}/Streaming/Channels/2'.format(username, password, camera_ip)

        # Flag to check if camera is valid/working
        self.online = False
        self.capture = None
        self.video_frame = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.load_network_stream()

        # Start background frame grabbing
        self.get_frame_thread = Thread(target=self.get_frame, args=())
        self.get_frame_thread.daemon = True
        self.get_frame_thread.start()

        # Periodically set video frame to display
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.set_frame)
        self.timer.start(.5)

        print('Started camera: {}'.format(self.camera_stream_link))

    def load_network_stream(self):
        """Verifies stream link and open new stream if valid"""

        def load_network_stream_thread():
            if self.verify_network_stream(self.camera_stream_link):
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_stream_link)
                self.online = True
        self.load_stream_thread = Thread(target=load_network_stream_thread, args=())
        self.load_stream_thread.daemon = True
        self.load_stream_thread.start()

    def verify_network_stream(self, link):
        """Attempts to receive a frame from given link"""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False
        cap.release()
        return True

    def get_frame(self):
        """Reads frame, resizes, and converts image to pixmap"""

        while True:
            try:
                if self.capture.isOpened() and self.online:
                    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
                    status, frame = self.capture.read()
                    if status:
                        self.deque.append(frame)
                    else:
                        self.capture.release()
                        self.online = False
                else:
                    # Attempt to reconnect
                    print('attempting to reconnect', self.camera_stream_link)
                    self.load_network_stream()
                    self.spin(2)
                self.spin(.001)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def spin(self, seconds):
        """Pause for set amount of seconds, replaces time.sleep so program doesnt stall"""

        time_end = time.time() + seconds
        while time.time() < time_end:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()

    def set_frame(self):
        """Sets pixmap image to video frame"""

        if not self.online:
            self.spin(1)
            return

        if self.deque and self.online:
            # Grab latest frame
            frame = self.deque[-1]

            # Keep frame aspect ratio
            if self.maintain_aspect_ratio:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=self.screen_width)
            # Force resize
            else:
                self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
                self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = self.frame.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w

            # Convert to pixmap and set to video frame
            self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
            self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)

    def get_video_frame(self):
        return self.video_frame


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, username, password, camera_ip, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # Top frame
        self.top_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.top_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")

        self.camera = CameraWidget(username, password, camera_ip)
        self.top_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.top_layout.addWidget(self.camera.get_video_frame())
        self.top_frame.setLayout(self.top_layout)


        # Bottom frame
        self.btm_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.btm_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Change Camera')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        self.btm_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btm_layout.addStretch()
        self.btm_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.btm_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.btm_frame.setLayout(self.btm_layout)


        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.top_frame, 20)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btm_frame,1)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def onClick(self):
        """
        I want this function to open a dialog box
        asking user to enter new cameras credentials
        and display it.
        """


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create main application window
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    w = MainWindow('admin', 'vaaan@123', '192.168.1.51')
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Initial answer

Is this close to what you have in mind?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import cv2
import imutils

class CameraWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # no change
    ...


class ChangeDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        QBtn = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        
        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QBtn)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.usernameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.passwordEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.passwordEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.ipAddrEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        vlayout.addWidget(self.usernameEdit)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.passwordEdit)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.ipAddrEdit)

        self.layout.addLayout(vlayout)
        self.layout.addWidget(buttonBox)

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.usernameEdit.text()

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.passwordEdit.text()

    @property
    def ipAddress(self):
        return self.ipAddrEdit.text()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, username, password, camera_ip, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # Top frame
        self.top_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.top_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")

        self.camera = CameraWidget(username, password, camera_ip)
        self.top_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.top_layout.addWidget(self.camera.get_video_frame())
        self.top_frame.setLayout(self.top_layout)


        # Bottom frame
        self.btm_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.btm_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(208, 208, 225)")

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Change Camera')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        self.btm_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btm_layout.addStretch()
        self.btm_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.btm_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.btm_frame.setLayout(self.btm_layout)


        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.top_frame, 20)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btm_frame,1)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.changeDialog = ChangeDialog()
        self.changeDialog.accepted.connect(self.changeCamera)


    def changeCamera(self):
        self.camera = CameraWidget(
            self.changeDialog.username,
            self.changeDialog.password,
            self.changeDialog.ipAddress)
        # not sure if this is necessary
        self.top_layout.takeAt(0)
        self.top_layout.addWidget(self.camera.get_video_frame())

    def onClick(self):
        """
        I want this function to open a dialog box
        asking user to enter new cameras credentials
        and display it.
        """
        self.changeDialog.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create main application window
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    w = MainWindow('admin', 'vaaan@123', '192.168.1.51')
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Without being able to actually see something it's hard to tell if something is missing, but this should be the right direction.

## Answering comments

### About mandatory fields

First of all this proposal is very rough.

You should add QLabels before each QLineEdit.

Then you should code some validation logic. You do this by removing the default "OK" button that I put in and put your own button. When this button is pressed, you check that each input `self` (the dialog) is valid.

If this is the case you can call [`accept()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept). Otherwise you can use [`setFocus()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1) on the first input that is invalid.

### Display previously entered data

In my proposal I created a dialog that is stored with the MainWindow.

It is never destroyed so all the data is still alive. When you display the dialog for the second time it still holds the previous data.

You can create a new dialog object each time if you prefer, or clear all inputs.

Comment: Can you make all these input fields as mandatory? and how are you able to display previously entered values in ```QLineEdit()```?